# Grabbing Image name From Product Image Gallery

Tags: php, functions

When a user clicks the add-to-cart button I need the order to capture the image from the product-image-gallery that the user last clicked **and NOT the default product image**. Is this possible?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Everything is possible, but what have you tried?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am not a developer so all I have tried is looking for a plugin to accomplish this, and have been unable to find one. I suspect this will need some JS. Any help is appreciated.